# Facebook offline access key / login issue

Tags: facebook, user-permissions, facebook-access-token

When the user accesses my apps for the first time, I ask for a couple of permissions (`user_checkins`, `publish_stream`, `offline_access`). After allowing all the permissions the user goes to privacy settings and removes one of the first 2 settings (not `offline_access`). Facebook doesn't ask him to allow back the removed permissions even if the user logs out and comes back to my applications.

The problem appeared when I started asking for offline access permissions, since the access token is not refreshed the token still contains the permission.

How can I request for a new token for the user with the right permissions?

Answer (score 2):

User will have to delete your application from his approve list and then access your app again. It will ask him to approve new permissions

Answer (score 0):

You can query the /me/permissions graph call (specifying the users access token) and check to see if the permissions you need are there.  If they are not, you can prompt them to re-authenticate with your application like you originally did and it will re-prompt them for those permissions.